# Flash - is there any control to render html 5 inside it?

Tags: flash, html

I am trying to build a flash application that will support the rendering of html5. Is there any built in web browser control that can help in doing that>

Comment: I've been looking for a similar solution, but have yet to find anything. I am hoping with their next version of Flash (or Edge, or Flex) they will have a solution for those of us that want to use HTML5.

Comment: Is the Flash application going to be used somewhere other than a browser?  Why not just use the browser to render HTML5?

Comment: because I must have the application written in flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and likely there won't be. Given that [Flash for mobile is dead](http://mashable.com/2011/11/09/its-official-flash-mobile-player-is-dead/), the only places you'll find Flash are places that will already display HTML5.

(...that is, if you're talking about the progressive-enhancement parts of HTML5, and you're talking about the common Flash plugin and not Adobe AIR.)

Comment: It is possible right now, in at least two ways:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/even-crazier-times-html-rendering-in-flashOne is a full-blown HTML renderer written in ActionScript, with CSS support.  It was last updated 4 years ago, but it's open source.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas  The other way uses Flash's externalInterface to run the HTML through Javascript's XML serializer, add the well-formed HTML to an XML SVG object as a foreignObject, render the whole thing to a canvas, and then acquire the image from the canvas.

Comment: Although neither of these methods would support user-interaction with the HTML content, the 2nd method may be a viable way to display complete and arbitrary HTML content in Flash using the browser's native rendering capabilities.  It would exist in Flash as a non-interactive image, but it could at least be situated anywhere within the display list.  Interactive components such as TextFields could always be overlayed.  Ultimately, once JavaScript catches up to AS3 and gets strong typing, I think we'll see an integrated native renderer for both Flash and HTML content systems.

Comment: This could also help pave the way, as its a full Flash Player implementation in JavaScript: http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/03/shumway-mozillas-html5-based-flash-player-replacement-lands-in-firefox-nightly/